# Cuda + OpenGL могут ли быть в одном проекте?

Tags: winforms, opengl, cuda

Как лучше осуществить взаимодействия Cuda и OpenGL? Мне нужно производить расчеты на Cuda и как-то отрисовать их.

Я не профессионал, могу ошибиться в технологиях, можете подсказать, как это лучше осуществить?

Answer (score 0):

Да это возможно. Вам необходимо изучать CUDA/OpenGL Interoperability:

- https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__OPENGL.html
- http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2012/presentations/S0267A-Mixing-Graphics-and-Compute-with-Multiple-GPUs-Part-A.pdf.

Если вам необходимо просто провести вычисления (CUDA не принципиальна) и отрисовать, то можете ещё изучить один из следующих подходов:

1. OpenCL/OpenGL Interoperability: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-and-opengl-interoperability-tutorial
2. Compute Shader: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Compute_Shader
3. Vulkan: http://www.duskborn.com/a-simple-vulkan-compute-example/